# Mudar HTML da paginação no Laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel-5

Existe uma maneira de alterar o HTML retornado pelo método `render()`, na paginação embutida no Laravel 5.1?

Nota: eu resolvi isto criando um helper que usa `str_replace()`, mas acredito que não seja o meio mais correto.

Grato.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontrei esta biblioteca - [Landish/Pagination](https://github.com/Landish/Pagination/) - que já traz alguns paginadores e permite facilmente criar seus próprios.

Answer (score 0):

Abre a página que contém a paginação.

Abre o Inspect Element do Chrome ou outro navegador que você usa e inspeciona os elementos que montam a paginação.

Altere via **CSS**.

Comment: Obrigado pela colaboração, no entanto, quero mudar o HTML mesmo.